# Check for overheat damage

Tags: overheating

I have a vehicle with a Chrysler 360 industrial application engine made in 1987 with 70k miles.

I haven't driven it before and I don't know the prior history.

recently I did drive it just a few hundred feet, after letting it idle for an hour.

Then it died and I noticed that it had very low oil and the radiator fans were not running.

Now I have changed the oil and the radiator fans run.

Question:
What diagnostics or visual inspections can I do to determine if there was any damage done by letting it run with no radiator fan and low oil?

Comment: Does it run now?

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to see any sign of Overheating directly. Basically you will only see something if there was damage done.
One possible consequence could be a warped head. This often leads to bad sealing at the head-gasket, usually leading to water-to-oil and oil-to-water leakage. This can be detected by looking into the oil-filler or taking of the valve cover and checking for a white emulsion, indicating that there is water in the oil.

Answer (score 2):

Low oil will lead to knocking or ticking.  Your main concern are spun rod bearings or main bearing.  You may also have wear on the cam.  Lifter tick will typically clear up on its own.  Listen for knocking, and watch your oil pressure.  Gouges will raise the area oil can pump into, lowering pressure.

Overheating - main concern is warping the cylinder head.  Easiest check is to do a compression test.  The cylinders should be within 10% of each other.  Typically 120 minimum.  Also, watch for smoke from the exhaust that smells like coolant.  You could also be coolant and oil mixing